# Javascript How to escape \u in string literal

Tags: javascript, unicode, escaping, backslash

Strange thing...

I have a string literal that is passed to my source code as a constant token (I cannot prehandle or escape it beforehand).

Example

```
var username = "MYDOMAIN\tom";
username = username.replace('MYDOMAIN','');
```

The string somewhere contains a backslash followed by a character.
It's too late to escape the backslash at this point, so I have to escape these special characters individually like

```
username = username.replace(/\t/ig, 't');
```

However, that does not work in the following scenario:

```
var username = "MYDOMAIN\ulrike";
```

\u seems to introduce a unicode character sequence. \uLRIK cannot be interpreted as a unicode sign so the Javascript engine stops interpreting at this point and my replace(/\u/ig,'u') comes too late.

Has anybody a suggestion or workaround on how to escape such a non-unicode character sequence contained in a given string literal? It seems a similar issue with \b like in "MYDOMAIN\bernd".

Comment: You're providing scope for passing illegal characters into the string. Not all characters can be escaped like that, so whatever is generating those strings needs to be changed

Comment: Javascript will consider the \ulrike as an invalid Unicode escape sequence.  The data needs to get escaped before it gets to the js var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a string literal that is passed to my source code

Assuming you don't have any < or >, move this to inside an HTML control (instead of inside your script block) or element and use Javacript to read the value. Something like

```
<div id="myServerData">
   MYDOMAIN\tom
</div>
```

and you retrieve it so

```
alert(document.getElementById("myServerData").innerText);
```

---

**IMPORTANT** : injecting unescaped content, where the user can control the content (say this is data entered in some other page) is a security risk. This goes for whether you are injecting it in script or HTML

Answer (score 1):

Writing `var username = "MYDOMAIN\ulrike";` will throw a syntax error. I think you have this string coming from somewhere.

I would suggest creating some html element and setting it's innerHTML to the received value, and then picking it up.

Have something like:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Then do `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = username;`

Then read the value from there as `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;`

This should work I guess.

**Important:** Please make sure this does not expose the webpage to script injections. If it does, this method is bad, don't use it.